# Optimizing route cost using derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> We are trying to transfer materials from city A to city B. The
>   material is being transfered from city A to a trading post on a 30km
>   long railway and then transfered by a car from the trading post to the
>   city B on a 9km long road. The road is perpendicular to the railroad.
>   Car travel costs $a/km$ and train travel costs $b/km$, where $a>b$.
>   Find the best spot for a new trading post on a railroad.

I think we have to find the new spot for the new trading post so that we minimaze the kilometers traveled by a car. However, I fail to create a function to derivate. I think we have to use law of sines?

Could you help me?

Comment: It's a good idea to draw the map and the possible road. Then try to form an expression for the total cost of the route. I think the function will be a sum of two terms.

Comment: @ Yes, but I have to know the length of the road. Not sure how to get that.

Comment: You can mark the location of the new trading post with $x$ (along the road) :). The cost will be then a function of $x$, and that's what you need to optimize.

Comment: @MattiP. Okay, but I know the length of railroad (distance between A and the new trading post). However, how do I calculate the length of the carroad? I have to somehow write the length of the carroad using just the railroad length, to get a function of single variable. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Well, it's assumed that the distance from A to B is fixed (some constant), and you know that the two lines are perpendicular to each other. Pythagoras?

Comment: @MattiP. Already did that and got the distance from A to B. However,  I still need the carroad length relative to the railroad length.

Comment: @MattiP. Okay, but that only applies in right triangle. When we move the trading post, the road will no longer be perpendicular to the railroad, right?

Comment: Ah yes, I think I little bit misunderstood the question. So I think the distance between $A$ and $B$ is
$$
\sqrt{30^2 + 9^2} \approx 31.32~\text{km}
$$
So first we ride along the railroad, for $x$ kilometers. Then, from there, we take a straight line to city $B$. The wording is a bit confusing in the problem.

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry, I tried to translate it as best as I could. Yes, first we take a train for $x$ kilometers by a railroad to the trading post. Then we go $y$ kilometers by a car straight to $B$. The distance between A to B is constant, as you said it is $31.32$km. There are no right angles, since the angle between the railroad and the carroad is no longer perpendicular. I think we are trying to minimize the kilometers taken by car, since car is more expensive then train. Therefore we have to choose a new trading post so that the car road is shortest possible.

Comment: @MattiP. Question is, how do we from a single variable function? I think we have to use the constant distance $AB$ somehow.

Comment: I think the distance from the **new** trading post to city $B$ is something like
$$
\sqrt{(30-x)^2 + 9^2}
$$
where $x$ is the distance that we went by the railway. Here we see why it's inportant to really draw the picture ...

Comment: I also think that the real distance from $A$ to $B$ **is** that 31.32 km, because the triangle formed by the **old** trading post is a straight triangle.

Comment: @MattiP. But wouldn't that only apply when the road from the new trading post to the city B is perpendicular to the railroad?

Comment: No. Draw the picture and try to imagine how I made the expression. The term $30-x$ is the distance between the old and new trading posts. The angle at the old trading post is still a straight angle.

Comment: @MattiP. I did draw a picture but I never looked on it liked that. As soon as I drew a new trading post, I stopped looking at the old one and it's edges. Thank you very much, I get it now.